# Moving Object Not Stopping On Collision Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, mobile

I am developing an infinite tower jumping game using Unity2D, and currently working on a continually moving object which causes the player to die if contact is made. The player can also die if they either fall off of a platform or off-screen. All methods of death rely on a BoxCollider2D I am using as a Killbox (tagged accordingly) - the player sprite has a RigidBody2D and BoxCollider2D attached to it - so there is one attached to the main camera (it moves as the player sprite progresses through the level) and to the top of the moving object.

The current code I have works up to the point where the game over screen appears on player death, but the object continues to move whilst everything else stops.

Here is my code for the moving object:

```
public class Water : MonoBehaviour   {
private Collider2D playerCollider;
public ControllerNew thePlayer;

private float speed = 2f; 

public GameManager theGameManager;

//reference scoremanager
private ScoreManager theScoreManager;

bool shouldMove = true;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    theScoreManager = FindObjectOfType<ScoreManager>();
    thePlayer = FindObjectOfType<ControllerNew>();
    lastPlayerPosition = thePlayer.transform.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (shouldMove = true)
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        if (theScoreManager.scoreCount > 100 && shouldMove)
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.up * (speed+1) * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (theScoreManager.scoreCount > 250 && shouldMove)
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.up * (speed +2) * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (theScoreManager.scoreCount > 500 && shouldMove)
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.up * (speed+4) * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (theScoreManager.scoreCount > 1000 && theScoreManager.scoreCount > theScoreManager.hiScoreCount && shouldMove)
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.up * (speed+5) * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    }

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player New")
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.zero * (speed * 0) * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    //call object by its tag
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Killbox")
    {
        shouldMove = false;
        if (shouldMove = false){ 
        theGameManager.RestartGame();
        transform.position += Vector3.zero * (speed * 0) * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

---

---

Edit (Issue resolved)

So it turns out that after adding the Water.StopMoving() method into my controller script, the water had not been called as a GameObject in void Start(). Once this was added, the water object stopped on collision.

Just want to say thank you @D.B for your help and bearing with me - apologies if the info I gave wasn't everything you needed to be able to assist me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake on the first line of the `Update()` method :

```
if (shouldMove = true)
```

You set the bool to true, not comparing it. Use double `=` otherwise it will set the bool to true at every frame.

```
if (shouldMove == true)
```

By the way you can simplify this part :

```
//call object by its tag
if (other.gameObject.tag == "Killbox")
{
    shouldMove = false;
    theGameManager.RestartGame();
    transform.position += Vector3.zero * (speed * 0) * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

(You forgot a `=` too)

I made a test with this simplified script

```
void Update()
{
    if (shouldMove == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("move");
        transform.position += Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime * GetDifficultyFactor();

    }

}

private float GetDifficultyFactor()
{
    float factor = 1f;
    if(theScoreManager.scoreCount > 100)
    {
        factor += 1f;
    }

    if (theScoreManager.scoreCount > 250)
    {
        factor += 2f;
    }

    // Add all your speed modification condition here
    return factor;
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    Debug.Log("trigger");
    //call object by its tag
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Killbox")
    {
        Debug.Log("die");
        shouldMove = false;
    }
}
```

And it work fine. Are you sure you have a collider2D set to trigger on your charactert with the tag "Killbox" (with the first letter in uppercase ?). You should have a rigidbody2d on the character too.

Mistake come frome another part of your code or with some trouble with collider2D/tag/RigidBody2D. Without seeing all it's difficult to help you more.

You should try to add some `Debug.Log()` or use debugeur with breakpoint to be sure code enter into your "die" statement and then not going on the `Update` if statement. If yes, it's mean you probably set the `shouldMove` variable in another part of your script.

**Answer regarding discussion in comments**

I think you want to make this `OnTriggerEnter2D` logic in both script.

Without seeing all your project I suggest you to make a reference bewteen your character and your water script. Then when the player die the player script will call a method on water to stop it.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Water Water;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Killbox")
        {
            Debug.Log("die");
            Water.StopMoving();
        }
    }
}

public class Water : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool shouldMove;

    public void Update()
    {
        ...
    }

    public void StopMoving()
    {
        shouldMove = false;
    }

    // No Trigger logic here
}
```

Comment: I add more details and tested your script. It should work fine. Take some time to debug to be sure:
1) You reach the OnTriggerEnter2D and you set `shouldMove` to false.
2) Then on the next `Update` calé `shouldMove` is still set to false. If not that means your variable is set in another part of your code. You could show all references in your code. In Visual Studio and Visual studio code you could right click and "show references".

Comment: It still seems to be moving despite copying and pasting the code into Visual Studio.

I've checked the "Killbox" with the tag and it matches - just to let you know that the tag is for a BoxCollider2D component I am using to "catch" the player sprite if it falls off of a platform - I followed a YouTube tutorial for this and it works just fine.

The player sprite has Rigidbody2D and BoxCollider2D.

I do not have the moving object referenced anywhere else - it was referenced in the Game Manager script to reset its position when the game is restarted, but this is currently commented out.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your code pass on the if tag "Killbox" ? Did you check with a breakpoint or a debug log? Can you show us screen of your character and water inspector view ?

Comment: Where did you put the debug log? Just to understand : here you have a water script who make the water go up. When the water collide a killbox it makes the game over and stop the water. You are telling me something different. You are telling me that's the player is going up and need to be stopped when it collides a killbox. Is your player water?

Comment: But is there a link between your character and the water ? If the character touch a killbox you should give the infornation to the water script. It don't not know that the character touch a killbox. Maybe a manager script should call a `StopMoving` method on your water when your character is killed. Or the character script. Two monobehaviour don't share their variables. The `shouldMove` is not share by different instance of script.

Comment: Did your player have a collider2d on trigger with a rigidbody2D ans the correct tag ? Can your make a screen. Because my exemple work I think you should give us more information about how your system works if you want more help.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your project? Otherwise can you explain your character code, your water code etc. I'm not sure to understand anymore. Maybe post Both code.

Comment: I've added extra info in my post, but I'm not sure what exactly you need to know more about - I have added the water script as the original post and explained that I just need for it to stop once the player makes contact with it.

The player sprite has RigidBody2D and BoxCollider2D so that the OnTriggerEnter2D function can operate which it does, but the object will not stop moving.

Comment: The water still moves even after I've changed the code to what you have suggested. I declared values for the shouldMove at different parts of the code rather than as true at the beginning, but this doesn't seem to have helped.